# Make Image occupy both columns of a 2-column paper, but be smaller

Tags: graphics, latex

in my LaTex file, I would like the picture of my 2-column paper to occupy the 2 columns of my paper, but I wanted to reduce the height of my picture to be smaller. Is it possible? Right now I'm just using:

```
\begin{figure*}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{diagramaheuristicasfluxonew}
  \caption{Flow Diagram of the Heuristic Development Process.}
\end{figure*}
```

[image: the image is too big for my PDF, I want the height of it to be smaller]

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how, just put a number before \textwidth and check image size through trial and error:

```
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{diagramaheuristicasfluxonew}
  \caption{Flow Diagram of the Heuristic Development Process.}
\end{figure*}
```